# Fine Structure question?

Tags: experimental-physics, atomic-physics, x-rays, x-ray-crystallography

My questions are:

1. In the case of pure metal are the R space peaks shifted from their expected positions.
2. Is there data base for pure metals bond lengths extracted .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FT peaks are always shifted by about 0.5 angstroms from  the positions that corresponds to the true interatomic distances. In the case of EXAFS from monoatomic systems, however, so called phase-shift correction can be done that puts the FT peaks at right positions. For this procedure one needs to calculate theoretically the complex scattering function, for instance, by program FEFF.